# Grails 2.4.0. dependency issues with jms 1.3 plugin & cache

Tags: grails

I am using Grails 2.4.0. Looking for help with dependency issue (I believe) I am having.

My application needs to talk to external ActiveMQ. I added jms1.3 plugin to my app and ran "grails compile". With jms plugin, following compilation errors shows up.

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
..........
|Compiling 199 source files
.Error 
|
Compilation error: startup failed:
Abnormal termination of javac.
C:\workspace_kepler\test\target\work\plugins\cache-1.1.7\src\java\grails\plugin\cache\GrailsCache.java:19: error: package org.springframework.cache does not exist
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
                                ^
C:\workspace_kepler\test\target\work\plugins\cache-1.1.7\src\java\grails\plugin\cache\GrailsCache.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
public interface GrailsCache extends Cache {
                                     ^
  symbol: class Cache
C:\workspace_kepler\test\target\work\plugins\cache-1.1.7\src\java\grails\plugin\cache\CacheBeanPostProcessor.java:25: error: package org.springframework.cache.annotation does not exist
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.AnnotationCacheOperationSource;
....
.....
```

BuildConfig.groovy

```
grails.servlet.version = "3.0" // Change depending on target container compliance (2.5 or 3.0)
grails.project.class.dir = "target/classes"
grails.project.test.class.dir = "target/test-classes"
grails.project.test.reports.dir = "target/test-reports"
grails.project.work.dir = "target/work"
grails.project.target.level = 1.6
grails.project.source.level = 1.6
grails.server.port.http = 8090
//grails.project.war.file = "target/${appName}-${appVersion}.war"

grails.project.fork = [
    // configure settings for compilation JVM, note that if you alter the Groovy version forked compilation is required
    //  compile: [maxMemory: 256, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],

    // configure settings for the test-app JVM, uses the daemon by default
    test: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, daemon:true],
    // configure settings for the run-app JVM
    run: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the run-war JVM
    war: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256, forkReserve:false],
    // configure settings for the Console UI JVM
    console: [maxMemory: 768, minMemory: 64, debug: false, maxPerm: 256]
]

grails.project.dependency.resolver = "maven" // or ivy
grails.project.dependency.resolution = {
    // inherit Grails' default dependencies
    inherits("global") {
        // specify dependency exclusions here; for example, uncomment this to disable ehcache:
        // excludes 'ehcache'
    }
    log "error" // log level of Ivy resolver, either 'error', 'warn', 'info', 'debug' or 'verbose'
    checksums true // Whether to verify checksums on resolve
    legacyResolve false // whether to do a secondary resolve on plugin installation, not advised and here for backwards compatibility

    repositories {
        inherits true // Whether to inherit repository definitions from plugins

        grailsPlugins()
        grailsHome()
        //mavenLocal()
        grailsCentral()
        mavenCentral()
        // uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable remote dependency resolution from public Maven repositories
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.codehaus.org"
        //mavenRepo "http://download.java.net/maven/2/"
        //mavenRepo "http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/"
    }

    dependencies {
        // specify dependencies here under either 'build', 'compile', 'runtime', 'test' or 'provided' scopes e.g.
        runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29'
        // runtime 'org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41'
        compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0', {
            excludes 'spring-asm'
        }
        compile "org.springframework:spring-orm:$springVersion"
    }

    plugins {
       // plugins for the build system only
        build ":tomcat:7.0.54"

        // plugins for the compile step
        compile ":scaffolding:2.1.2"
        compile ':cache:1.1.7'
        compile ":asset-pipeline:1.8.11"
        compile ":jms:1.3"
        compile ":cache-headers:1.1.7"
        compile ":marshallers:0.5"

        // plugins needed at runtime but not for compilation
        runtime ":hibernate4:4.3.5.4" // or ":hibernate:3.6.10.15"
        runtime ":database-migration:1.4.0"
        runtime ":jquery:1.11.1"
        runtime ":resources:1.2.8"
        runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
        runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.5"

    }
//  
//  management {
//      dependency "commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3"
//  }
}
```

Dependency Report:

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.0
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to development
.
build - Dependencies for the build system only (total: 32)
+--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
+--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|    \--- jline:jline:2.11
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-trax:1.7.1
|    \--- net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.0.0
|    \--- org.apache.ant:ant-junit:1.8.4
|    \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|    \--- org.apache.ivy:ivy:2.3.0
|    \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
+--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-scripts:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-docs:2.4.0
|    \--- org.xhtmlrenderer:core-renderer:R8
|    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.8
|    \--- org.grails:grails-gdoc-engine:1.0.1
|    \--- org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3
|    \--- com.lowagie:itext:2.0.8
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:138
|         \--- bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:138
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails.plugins:tomcat:7.0.54
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-catalina-ant:7.0.53
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:7.0.53
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:7.0.53
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.53
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:7.0.53
|    \--- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:3.7.2
|    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:7.0.53


provided - Dependencies needed at development time, but not during deployment (total: 1)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1


compile - Dependencies placed on the classpath for compilation (total: 87)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.0
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.0
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.0
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.0
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.0
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.0
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.0
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.0
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.0
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.0
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.0
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.0
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.0
|         \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.0
|              \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    \--- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:5.7.0
|    \--- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:1.1
|    \--- org.fusesource.mqtt-client:mqtt-client:1.3
|         \--- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch-transport:1.11
|              \--- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch:1.11
|         \--- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:1.9
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:1.0.1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-net:commons-net:3.1
|    \--- org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.0
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.7
|    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.8.11
+--- org.grails.plugins:jms:1.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.4.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache-headers:1.1.7
+--- org.grails.plugins:marshallers:0.5


runtime - Dependencies needed at runtime but not for compilation (total: 121)
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.0
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.0
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.0
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.0
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.0
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.0
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.0
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.0
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.0
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.0
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.0
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.0
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.0
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.0
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.0
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.0
|         \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.0
|              \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.173
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.0
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29
+--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    \--- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:5.7.0
|    \--- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:1.1
|    \--- org.fusesource.mqtt-client:mqtt-client:1.3
|         \--- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch-transport:1.11
|              \--- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch:1.11
|         \--- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:1.9
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:1.0.1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-net:commons-net:3.1
|    \--- org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.0
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.7
|    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.8.11
|    \--- org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.4
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.1.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|         \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.1.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:jms:1.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.4.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.8
+--- org.grails.plugins:cached-resources:1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:zipped-resources:1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:yui-minify-resources:0.1.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache-headers:1.1.7
+--- org.grails.plugins:marshallers:0.5


test - Dependencies needed for test compilation and execution but not at runtime (total: 135)
+--- javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.0.1
+--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.1
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-rest:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-controllers:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-validation:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource:2.4.0
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-logging-log4j:7.0.50
|         \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-jdbc:7.0.50
|              \--- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-juli:7.0.50
|    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5
|    \--- org.grails:grails-web:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-gsp:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-databinding:2.4.0
|              \--- org.grails:grails-databinding:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-sitemesh:2.4.0
|              \--- opensymphony:sitemesh:2.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-mvc:2.4.0
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-jsp:2.4.0
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:1.8.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-common:2.4.0
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.5.RELEASE
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-context-support:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:1.8.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-url-mappings:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-web-fileupload:2.4.0
|              \--- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.3.1
|                   \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.2
|    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-core:2.4.0
|         \--- org.grails:grails-bootstrap:2.4.0
|         \--- xalan:serializer:2.7.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-spring:2.4.0
|         \--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|         \--- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.1-api:1.0.0.Final
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-i18n:2.4.0
|    \--- commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-filters:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-logging:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs:2.4.0
|         \--- commons-codec:commons-codec:1.6
|         \--- org.grails:grails-encoder:2.4.0
|              \--- org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-log4j:2.4.0
|    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:1.7.5
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-services:2.4.0
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-servlets:2.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings:2.4.0
|    \--- com.googlecode.concurrentlinkedhashmap:concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru:1.4
|    \--- org.grails:grails-validation:2.4.0
|         \--- commons-validator:commons-validator:1.4.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-async:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-async:2.4.0
|         \--- org.codehaus.gpars:gpars:1.2.0
|              \--- org.codehaus.jsr166-mirror:jsr166y:1.7.0
+--- org.grails:grails-plugin-testing:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-test:2.4.0
|         \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:1.4
|         \--- org.grails:grails-project-api:2.4.0
|              \--- org.apache.ant:ant:1.8.4
|                   \--- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:1.8.4
|              \--- jline:jline:2.11
|              \--- org.codehaus.gant:gant_groovy1.8:1.9.6
|              \--- org.fusesource.jansi:jansi:1.11
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-domain-class:2.4.0
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-test:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-mimetypes:2.4.0
|    \--- org.grails:grails-plugin-converters:2.4.0
+--- org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0
|    \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
+--- junit:junit:4.11
+--- com.h2database:h2:1.3.173
+--- log4j:log4j:1.2.17
+--- org.grails:grails-resources:2.4.0
+--- mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.29
+--- org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.7.0
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jms_1.1_spec:1.1.1
|    \--- org.apache.activemq:kahadb:5.7.0
|    \--- org.apache.activemq.protobuf:activemq-protobuf:1.1
|    \--- org.fusesource.mqtt-client:mqtt-client:1.3
|         \--- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch-transport:1.11
|              \--- org.fusesource.hawtdispatch:hawtdispatch:1.11
|         \--- org.fusesource.hawtbuf:hawtbuf:1.9
|    \--- org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-j2ee-management_1.1_spec:1.0.1
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:3.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-aop:3.0.7.RELEASE
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:3.0.7.RELEASE
|    \--- commons-net:commons-net:3.1
|    \--- org.jasypt:jasypt:1.9.0
+--- org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.0.5.RELEASE
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.0.5.RELEASE
|         \--- commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:4.0.5.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:scaffolding:2.1.2
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache:1.1.7
|    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA
|    \--- org.grails.plugins:webxml:1.4.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline:1.8.11
|    \--- org.mozilla:rhino:1.7R4
+--- org.grails.plugins:hibernate4:4.3.5.4
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.0.3.Final
|         \--- com.fasterxml:classmate:1.0.0
|    \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:4.3.5.Final
|         \--- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:4.3.5.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:1.0.0.Final
|              \--- antlr:antlr:2.7.7
|              \--- org.jboss:jandex:1.1.0.Final
|    \--- net.sf.ehcache:ehcache-core:2.4.8
|    \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:3.1.0.GA
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-core:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate4:3.1.1.RELEASE
|         \--- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:4.0.4.Final
|              \--- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging-annotations:1.2.0.Beta1
|         \--- dom4j:dom4j:1.6.1
|         \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-hibernate-core:3.1.1.RELEASE
|              \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-gorm-plugin-support:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- org.grails:grails-datastore-simple:3.1.1.RELEASE
|    \--- javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final
+--- org.grails.plugins:database-migration:1.4.0
|    \--- org.liquibase:liquibase-core:2.0.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:jquery:1.11.1
+--- org.grails.plugins:jms:1.3
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jms:3.1.4.RELEASE
+--- org.grails.plugins:resources:1.2.8
+--- org.grails.plugins:cached-resources:1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:zipped-resources:1.0
+--- org.grails.plugins:yui-minify-resources:0.1.5
+--- org.grails.plugins:cache-headers:1.1.7
+--- org.grails.plugins:marshallers:0.5
```

Comment: Why not try upgrading to 2.4.2?

Comment: I am facing the same problem? Please let me know if you managed to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Dependency declaration -:
The JMS plugin is provider-agnostic, so we have to declare a dependency on ActiveMQ in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy (Listing 1 – for simplicity we can borrow the dependency from the plugin test scope) and uncomment the mavenCentral() repository.

view sourceprint?
01.
compile('org.apache.activemq:activemq-core:5.3.0',
02.
'org.apache.activemq:activeio-core:3.1.2',
03.
'org.apache.xbean:xbean-spring:3.7') {
04.
excludes 'activemq-openwire-generator'
05.
excludes 'commons-logging'
06.
excludes 'xalan'
07.
excludes 'xml-apis'
08.
exported = false
09.
}